# What's the fastest way to earn XP?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, I want to hit the level cap as fast as possible to get as many skills as possible, to get more money whereas constituent parts remain the same price, to get weapons that I won't be ditching in a few levels, etc.. What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: edit your char so they're max level? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways: alter game files, redo challenges, play in someone else's game, repeatedly turn in continuous events, and/or repeatedly break zombie arms. I'm assuming that these options may be faster than simply playing through the game.

- To get it out of the way, [repeatedly breaking the same zombie's arm(s)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47IT-T66IEY) was patched out, [according](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/dead_island_solo_62.html) to TheVoid (SDA). This may still be viable if you are not on the latest patch (1.3).
- As spartacus [commented](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116018/whats-the-fastest-way-to-earn-xp/116026?noredirect=1#comment155936_116018) and kotekzot [answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116026/46216), your save file can be
  edited to award you more skill points.
- Anonymous claims that challenges can be exploited to earn XP from completing the same challenge over and over.
  "1. Get a challenge up to where its about to finished. 2. switch to a character you want to give the XP to. 3. finish the challenge. 4. IMMEDIATELY turn off the game without getting a check-point. 5. turn on the game. 6. Repeat steps 3-6." - http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Power_leveling_glitch
- If you're playing in someone else's game and the host is a higher level than you or has progressed further, there'll be enemies that are higher level than you. They will not be higher level than you if you have the enemy-level-adjustment option turned on. Higher level enemies means more XP from their defeat.
- Continuous events means those neverending side-quests where you can interact with the quest-giver to give them a constituent part or stackable that they seek, and they reward you with a different item, XP, and/or cash. These combined with a convenient source of sought item (read: duplication) makes for fast XP.
  I usually use Svetlana in the [Time for Booze](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Time_for_Booze) continuous event out at the north-east corner of the resort, over-the-water bungalows. I suspect [Blood Compound](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Compound) is also fast, assuming a correlation between rarity of parts and size of XP reward, and that the Wiki article I linked to claims that it rewards more XP than Time for Booze. However, the XP reward [scales](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTuOHPa3GhM).

Comment: My answer isn't about editing game files, it's about editing saves.

Comment: I use the term "file" generally, just as I do with "items". My perspective is from playing on OnLive where I cannot access any game files outside of the game client, such as raw saves or tweaking the physics of the game. Tell me, what is a term that encompasses both "saves" and "game files" as you see it? How else would you define "game files" as you see it mutually exclusive? I can understand what you mean, but I'd like a term.

Comment: I don't think there is such a term, they are different enough to warrant different names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dead Island Save Editor](http://deadislandsaveeditor.steffenl.com/) to set your level to whatever you want. The game will automatically give you any missing skill points when you load up your save.

Answer (score 0):

In Dead Island 1 it's usually doing quests, or you can find a thug spawn and find a checkpoint near there or run from one to another and then in killing the thug make sure to break it's arms first and then kill it. For example there is a thug (after you first encounter them) that always spawns on the beach near the tiny island bar, and all the other tiny island bars. You can kill one, run the beach to the next one kill that and then go back to the first and it should respawn.

Other methods of earning money, is just expand your item slots or use the ones you have available as "carries" for things to pickup and sell, and a few things to keep for the next level (that's what I did and saved about 50k.

In Dead Island Riptide the fatest way to level is to take the continuous quests, one from Chimamanda for canned food, go and farm canned food - in Riptide these quests give enormous amounts of XP and I think this is how I leveled up so quickly - went from 15 - 54 in one rushed playthrough.

Comment: @NiteCyper - why are you answering your own questions?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ And you should've made that comment on my answer rather than your own.

Comment: It would only let me comment on my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the arena, and just farm like crazy, kill everything with elemental weapons a certain number of times, its 80,000xp for so many floaters killed and there are plenty in the later rounds.

Answer (score -1):

Download the bloodbath arena if it doesn't work try going to C ex and u will be able to buy the game of the year edition and you will have all editional content then complete the mission where you get rid of the undead in the life guard tower then go to fast travel go down to arena lobby and try to 
Survive waves of zombies but get some guns and some good modified weapons then you should level up fast for completing the challenges every 2 waves